# Show and group all records with the same id with two fields that are not null

Tags: mysql, select

I have a table that shows all the products, the price_fact field, calculates the average when invoiced and updates the price_fact field when it makes an insert, and the price_alb field is the same but with a delivery note.

So when invoice (price_fact) has no delivery note (price_alb) and when it is delivery note has no invoice.

```
+---------------+------------+-------+-------------+-----------+
| name          | id_product | price |   price_fact|  price_alb|
+---------------+------------+-------+-------------+-----------+
| phone         |         1  |   300 |        NULL |        275| 
| mouse         |         2  |   100 |        100  |       NULL|        
| phone         |         1  |   250 |        NULL |        275|
| mouse         |         2  |   100 |        NULL |        100| 
| phone         |         1  |   300 |        300  |       NULL|
+---------------+------------+------+--------------+-----------+
```

And what I want is to calculate all the products in a single row, the number of products in total and the final result shows the column price_fact and price_alb of that product, of those who have had records that are not null.

```
+---------------+------------+-------+-------------+-----------+------+
| name          | id_product | price |   price_fact|  price_alb| units|
+---------------+------------+-------+-------------+-----------+------+
| phone         |         1  |   300 |         300 |        275|     3|
| mouse         |         2  |   100 |         100 |        100|     2|   
+---------------+------------+------+--------------+-----------+------+
```

Solved (I have put MAX(price_fact), MAX(price_alb) in select).

Comment: Why did mouse`price = 50` in your expect result?

Comment: I have the solution now, only put MAX(price_alb), MAX(price_fact).

Comment: But I am curious how can do you get `price = 50` instead of 100

Comment: I sorry I have calculated wrong when I have written. It's 100.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use aggregate function.

```
SELECT name,
       id_product,
       MAX(price) price,
       MAX(price_fact) price_fact,
       MAX(price_alb) price_alb,
       COUNT(*) units
FROM T
GROUP BY name,id_product
```